# ¿Como darle estilo a un input="file"?

Tags: html, css

Me gustaría que un input (**`<input type='file' >`**).
Tenga la apariencia de un div con una class la cual le da foma de circulo.

```css
circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 80%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 80%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #f0f2f7;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

En este caso pues aplique ciertos estilos a los divs, para que de esta forma no apareciera el input file si no el circulo que tu deseas

```css
.fileContainer {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.fileContainer [type=file] {
    cursor: inherit;
    display: block;
    font-size: 999px;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-align: right;
    top: 0;
}

.fileContainer {
    border-radius: 50%;
  width: 80%;
  height:0;
  padding-bottom: 80%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #f0f2f7;
  background:gray;
}

.fileContainer [type=file] {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="fileContainer">
    <input type="file"/>
</div>
```

Comment: La idea en las respuestas es explicar la solución, no solo poner "espero que te sirva".

Answer (score 2):

Podrías realizarlo ocultando el `input type="file"` y estilizando una `label` conectada a el mediante el atributo `for`.

De esta manera, cuando des click sobre la `label` (la cual podrás estilizar), se lanzará el evento del `input type="file"` que se encuentra oculto y te permitirá elegir un archivo.

```css
#fichero{
  display: none;
}

.circle{
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input id="fichero" type="file">
<label for="fichero" class="circle"></label>
```

**NOTA:** Ten en cuenta que el ID del `input` tiene que ser el mismo que el valor del atributo `for` de la `label`.

Answer (score 0):

quizá esta forma te sirva. Colocas un seudoelemento after o before y colocas al input posición relativa y al seudoelemento posición absoluta y lo tapas. De igual forma cuando presiones el seudoelemento, se te abrirá el buscador de archivos.

```
input[type="file"]{
    position: relative;}

input[type="file"]::after{
    position: absolute;
    content: "Seleccionar archivo";
    padding: .8rem 1rem;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    background-color: $gris;
    top:.5rem;
    left: .7rem;
    cursor: pointer;}


<label for="imagen">Imagen:</label>
<input type="file" id="imagen" >
```

Comment: Hola Facu, bienvenido, mira [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para evitar votos negativos y/o que tu repuesta sea eliminada, y de paso, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!